# Proving that $(e^T)^{-1} = e^{-T}$ using term-by-term multiplication of the series for $e^T e^{-T}$

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, operator-theory

My question comes from *Differential Dynamical* Systems by Meiss, page 40. The author makes the following claim: If $T: E \rightarrow E$ is a bounded linear operator, then $$(e^T)^{-1} = e^{-T}.$$
The author does not prove the claim, he just writes "(term-by-term multiplication of the series for $e^T e^{-T}$)" next to it. I tried to verify this using the Cauchy product formula as follows:
\begin{align*}
    e^T e^{-T} &= \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{T^n}{n!} \right) \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-T)^n}{n!} \right) \\[5pt]
     &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n}   \frac{T^k}{k!} \frac{(-1)^{n-k}\, T^{n-k}}{(n-k)!} \\[5pt]
     &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} T^n \sum_{k=0}^{n}  \frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{k! (n-k)!} \ \\[5pt]
\end{align*}

At this point, I don't know really know how to proceed to show that the result is the identity map. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not really so much "the Cauchy Product Formula", as just the inevitable expression for the product (assuming convergence).

Comment: This is just [DLMF 1.2.E4](https://dlmf.nist.gov/1.2.E4) special case of binomial theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now, use the fact that$$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^n}{k!(n-k)!}=\bigl(1+(-1)\bigr)^n=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }n=0\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Ah, the binomial theorem! Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.